# Why do the characters take the year 2060 for granted?

Tags: pending-train

In the Japanese science fiction/mystery series [*Pending Train*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt27591951/), a group of metro travellers get stranded in what appears to be a deserted future with only few traces of civilization left.

In one of the first episodes, they encounter a character who tells them it is the year 2060

> and a catastrophe had struck in 2026, all of which he had learned by making radio contact with someone in Canada.

In a later episode (around 1x07), it becomes evident that said character

> had been lying about the radio contact as the radio had never been working. He stated all of

his information about the catastrophe was from a booklet he found aboard an abandoned yacht.

All protagonists are informed about this.

Yet, dialogue makes it clear that in episode 1x08, the characters still assume they are in 2060. It is unclear how long the booklet may have been lying around there, so **why does everyone assume their information about the year they are in is accurate?**